# React re-renders entire list of components even with unique keys

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using the React useState hook to update a list of items. I would like for only the added/updated components to be rendered but everytime the state of of the list changes all the items in list are re-rendered.

I have followed [Preventing list re-renders. Hooks version.](https://staleclosures.dev/preventing-list-rerenders/#:%7E:text=Every%20time%20we%20delete%20one,render%20all%20of%20its%20children.&text=React%20will%20shallowly%20compare%20props,if%20they%20stayed%20the%20same.) to solve the re-render issue but it doesn't work

Can someone help me understand, what's wrong with the below code or if this is actually not the right way to do it

```
function App() {

    const [arr, setArr] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        //getList here returns a list of elements of the form {id: number, name: string}
        setArr(getList());
    }, [])

    const clickHandle = useCallback((e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setArr((arr) => {
            return [...arr, {
                id: id + 100,
                name: `test${id+100}`
            }]

        })
    }, [arr])

    return ( 
    <div className="App">
      {
        arr.map((item) => {
          
          return (
            <NewComp key={`${item.id}`} item={item} clickHandle={clickHandle} />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
    );
}

const NewComp = ({
    item,
    clickHandle
}) => {
    return ( 
    <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => clickHandle(e, item.id)}>{item.name}</button>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason all your NewComp re-render is because your clickHandle function is being recreated whenever there is any change in the state arr.

This happens because you have added `arr` as a dependency to useCallback. This however is not required.

Once you fix it, you can wrap your `NewComp` with `React.memo` to optimize their re-renders. Also you must note that call the render function of a component is different from actually re-rendering it in the DOM.

```
const clickHandle = useCallback((e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setArr((arr) => {
        return [...arr, {
            id: id + 100,
            name: `test${id+100}`
        }]

    })
}, []);
```

---

```
const NewComp = React.memo({
    item,
    clickHandle
}) => {
    return ( 
    <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => clickHandle(e, item.id)}>{item.name}</button>
    </div>
    );
});
```